# JavaFX LineChart showing right result in one computer and wrong in other

Tags: java, javafx

So, we're doing a home assignment in Java and for UI i used JavaFX. So my program works, draws a linechart like a charm and no problem. When my classmate did the same thing, his didn't. Dude sent me his code, i ran it and in my computer everything was fine. What could cause something like that - linechart showing wrong in one computer and right in other?

The data is added to the chart in the same way, in my computer the data is shown in the way it's entered to the chart but in his computer it's in wrong order (the elements are sorted for some reason).

[image: The wrong version]
[image: My computer version]

```
public LineChart createChart(ArrayList elements) throws PoleValitudErind{
            //Elements entered or chosen, in the right order!
            ArrayList fixedLst = new ArrayList();
            int s = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i<elements.size();i++){
                    s = (int) elements.get(i);
                    fixedLst.add(s);
            }
            String strStart = tf2.getText();
            int intStart = 0;
            try {
                    intStart = Integer.parseInt(strStart);
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException j){
                    throw new PoleValitudErind();
            }
    final NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
    final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
    final LineChart<Number,Number> lineChart =
            new LineChart<Number,Number>(xAxis,yAxis);
    XYChart.Series series = new XYChart.Series();
    series.setName("Radade vahetus");
    //populating the series with data
    series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(intStart,0));
    int counter = 1;
    for (int j = 0;j<fixedLst.size();j++){
            series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(fixedLst.get(j),counter));
            counter += 1;

    }
    //System.out.println(series.getData());
    lineChart.getData().add(series);
    lineChart.setMaxHeight(150);
    return lineChart;
    }
```

Comment: Are you using the same versions (both Java and JavaFX) ?

Comment: As just the _line connections_ of the diagram points seem to differ, then the JavaFX versions must differ; he having a slightly buggy charting. I would still check whether some platform check is done: you both seem to have different platforms.

Comment: @JoopEggen yes, we did, he was in Eclipse Luna and i was in Eclipse Kepler. However, if he changed his code to Kepler, his didn't work either.

Comment: Are you using Java 8 + JavaFX 2 and he maybe Java 7, that had an older JavaFX?

Comment: From the pics, one is using Java 8 (8u25, the last official update, with JavaFX 8) and the other one is using Java 7 (not specified, but with JavaFX 2). Many bugs have been fixed in between.

Comment: Yes, we indeed have a difference between Java Versions and JavaFX versions. Although mine is lower and older version than his. Could it be that upgraded JavaFX Charts are just bad?

Comment: You could just test that by running it on Java 7 on your machine...